# How to find best plane passes through the center of $n$ points

Tags: calculus, least-squares

Consider $n$ points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How to find the best plane passes through the center of these points with following approach:

If we assume that the such plane has form $w.x-\gamma=0$ then distance between this plane and any points $x_i$ is equal
$$D=\frac{\Vert w\cdot x_i-\gamma\Vert}{\Vert w\Vert}$$
and for the best plane passes through the center of these points the sum of all distances must be **minimized**.

Comment: Sure you don't want the sum of the squared distances to be minimized?  (usual "least square" error estimation).  Makes the differentiation a lot simpler.

Comment: What's the centre of the points? You mean the centre of mass?

Comment: I think in the displayed equation $x$ should be $x_i$?

Comment: @joriki Yes, centre of mass! Variable $x$ in plane equation is general.

Comment: Then perhaps the text is wrong? It talks about "distance between this plane and any points $x_i$", but $x_i$ doesn't occur anywhere.

Comment: The equation of a plane, $w$ would be an $(n-2)\times n$ matrix.  I guess it would be easier to give two unit perpendicular vectors rather than that.  Also, once you know the plane goes through the centre of mass, you can subtract that position from each $x_i$, and then $\gamma$ becomes zero.  I should have asked: is the plane two-dimensional or $n-1$-dimensional?

Comment: @Michael for simplicity let $n=2$.